# phph in_array does not find record

Tags: php

I am using in_array but it is coming back that that data I give it is not in the array although it should.

cant see what I am missing?

the array

```
array(3) { 
["MonthlyReturn"]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(3) "307" ["employee_id"]=> string(3) "553" } 
["Company"]=> array(13) { ["id"]=> string(3) "160" ["member_number"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(5) "ger 2"  } 
["Employee"]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> string(3) "553" ["company_id"]=> string(3) "160" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "pepe" }
```

The php code

```
$employee = 554;

if (in_array($employee, (array)$existingReturns['MonthlyReturn']['employee_id'])){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause it is not an array. Why just you don't check like this,

```
if ($employee == $existingReturns['MonthlyReturn']['employee_id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`$existingReturns['MonthlyReturn']` is the array, while `$existingReturns['MonthlyReturn']['employee_id']` is a string